# If $Y\ge 0$ almost surely and $X+Y \sim X$ then $Y=0$ almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

> Let $X, Y$ be random variables on the same probability space such that $Y \ge 0$ almost surely and $X+Y$ and $X$ have the same distribution. Please resolve whether these conditions imply that $\mathbb{P}(Y=0)=1$.

I'm highly convinced that there exists $Y$ such that $\mathbb{P}(Y=0)\neq1$ but I cannot come up with a construction. However it may be a simple question to someone with more experience so I decided to share the question.

Comment: Take any $Y \geq 0$, and $X=0$ :-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If** $X$ has finite first moment, then

$$
\Bbb{E}(X) + \Bbb{E}(Y) = \Bbb{E}(X+Y) = \Bbb{E}(X),
$$

so that subtraction of $\Bbb{E}(X)$ yields $\Bbb{E}(Y)=0$. Together with $Y\geq 0$  almost surely, this easily implies that $Y\equiv 0$  almost surely.

EDIT: Without assuming that $X$ has finite first moment, we can use the following "truncation" trick: For $n \in \Bbb{N}$, let $f_n (x) := \max\{-n,\min\{x,n\}\}$. Note that each $f_n$ is bounded and continuous with $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$. Furthermore, note that $f_n (x) \leq f_n (y)$ holds for $x \leq y$.

The assumption $X+Y \sim X$ implies

$$
\Bbb{E}(f_n(X+Y)) = \Bbb{E}(f_n(X)). \qquad (\dagger)
$$

Because of  $X \leq X+Y$ almost surely, we see that $f_n(X) \leq f_n(X+Y)$ almost surely, so that $(\dagger)$ implies that $f_n (X) = f_n(X+Y)$ almost surely. Hence,

$$
X+Y = \lim_n f_n(X+Y) = \lim_n f_n(X) = X
$$

almost surely, which implies that $Y=0$ almost surely.

Comment: Thank you for an answer! Yup I tried that firstly but unfortunately there is no such assumption (maybe that's mistake but I'm still trying to construct such $Y$ *without* finite first moment).

Comment: @StephenDedalus: I edited my post to also cover the case $\Bbb{E}(|X|) = \infty$.

Comment: Nice, +1. $ $ $ $